# RestSharp C# JsonDeserializer to List giving object property values as null

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have a json resultset as below in my response object

```
 [{
"id": "13",
"category_id": "[\"2\"]",
"store_id": "[\"3\"]",
"name": "Sp juise",
"price": "1",
"description": "<p><b><\/b><br><\/p>",
"image": "<p>You did not select a file to upload.<\/p>",
"active": "1"
}, {
"id": "12",
"category_id": "[\"2\"]",
"store_id": "[\"3\"]",
"name": "Sp juise",
"price": "1",
"description": "<p><b><\/b><br><\/p>",
"image": "<p>You did not select a file to upload.<\/p>",
"active": "1"
}, {
"id": "11",
"category_id": "[\"3\"]",
"store_id": "[\"2\"]",
"name": "Berger (Chicken)",
"price": "80",
"description": "<p>Chicken Berger<\/p>",
"image": "assets\/images\/product_image\/5b374e99c53ce.jpg",
"active": "1"
 }, {
"id": "10",
"category_id": "[\"2\"]",
"store_id": "[\"2\"]",
"name": "Juce",
"price": "2",
"description": "<p>mixed<\/p>",
"image": "<p>You did not select a file to upload.<\/p>",
"active": "1"
 }, {
"id": "9",
"category_id": "null",
"store_id": "null",
"name": "Orenge juse",
"price": "2.5",
"description": "",
"image": "assets\/images\/product_image\/5b374ece3d909.jpg",
"active": "1"

 }]
```

and the following class

```
 public class Product
 {
    public string id;
    public string category_id;
    public string store_id;
    public string name;
    public string price;
    public string description;
    public string image;
    public string active;

}
```

the below code for getting the list of products from the json

```
       RestHTTPClient.BaseUrl = new Uri(ServerURL + "/products/fetchProductJson");
        var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        var response2 = RestHTTPClient.Execute(request2);

        JsonDeserializer deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        var products = deserializer.Deserialize<List<Product>>(response2);



        var strok = response2.StatusCode.ToString();
        if (strok == "OK")
        {
            ProductsUI(products);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

products has objects can enumerate through but the fields are not mapped to the class properties and they all returning null values for each objects in the list.

Answer (score 1):

It was due to missing get and set
The below solved the issue

```
public class Product
    {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    public string store_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }

}
```